# Multiple Mailboxes in Exchange and transferring content between mailboxes inside of Outlook

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, mailbox

We have an Exchange 2010 SP3 system with Outlook 2007-2013. My manager had a request concerning people who showed multiple mailboxes in their Outlook, an example would be a manager having their own mailbox plus the mailbox of a recently terminated user.

Is there a way to prevent the manager from copying the content from the terminated employee to their own mailbox? The manager could view the emails in the ex-employee but could not move the information in or out.

This is related to e-discovery and controlling the email data.

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Nope - if they can read it, they can copy it.

You can set the access to Reviewer, so that nothing could be actually removed from or added to the terminated user, but you can't prevent simple copying of items.

Comment: I have kinda figured that but I wanted to have people who are wiser than I on the subject confirm or deny. Thanks so much for your help. Could the ex employee's mailbox still be added to the folder list in Outlook or would would you have to do a file/open/other user's mailbox to see it?

Comment: File->Open->Other user's mailbox *does* add it to the folder list in the left side of Outlook 2010/2013, for me - and it stays there. So I'm not sure what your question means.

Comment: Hmm, on my Outlook 2013 it does not show it on the left side, 2010 either. Let me further investigate..thanks